# Determining if a given string of words has words greater than 5 letters long

Tags: java, string

So, I'm in need of help on my homework assignment.  Here's the question:

> Write a static method, `getBigWords`, that gets a `String` parameter and returns an array whose elements are the words in the parameter that contain more than 5 letters. (A word is defined as a contiguous sequence of letters.) So, given a `String` like "There are 87,000,000 people in Canada", `getBigWords` would return an array of two elements, "people" and "Canada".

What I have so far:

```
public static getBigWords(String sentence)
{
  String[] a = new String;
  String[] split = sentence.split("\\s");
  for(int i = 0; i < split.length; i++)
  {
    if(split[i].length => 5)
    {
      a.add(split[i]);
    }
  }
  return a;
}
```

I don't want an answer, just a means to guide me in the right direction.  I'm a novice at programming, so it's difficult for me to figure out what exactly I'm doing wrong.

**EDIT:**

I've now modified my method to:

```
public static String[] getBigWords(String sentence)
{
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] split = sentence.split("\\s+");
    for(int i = 0; i < split.length; i++)
    {
        if(split[i].length() > 5)
        {
            if(split[i].matches("[a-zA-Z]+"))
            {
                result.add(split[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return result.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

It prints out the results I want, but the online software I use to turn in the assignment, still says I'm doing something wrong.  More specifically, it states:

```
Edith de Stance states:
⇒     You might want to use: +=
⇒     You might want to use: ==
⇒     You might want to use: +
```

not really sure what that means....

Comment: +1 for knowing how to ask for help with homework.

Comment: What results are you getting currently?

Comment: you wont be able to call `a.add` since it is an `array` not a `list`

Comment: @Kelvin, you should pay attention to usage of `array`, it has no `add` method, and also you should define a `return type` for your method. BTW, in your given string, isn't `87,000,000`'s length over 5?

Comment: Actually it's only supposed to return word strings, not numbers. Thank you so far for the feedback, I've now changed the String to ArrayList<String>

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that you can't have an array that makes itself bigger as you add elements.

You have 2 options:

- [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) (basically a variable-length array).
- Make an array guaranteed to be bigger.

Also, some notes:

The definition of an array needs to look like:

```
int size = ...;      //  V- note the square brackets here
String[] a = new String[size];
```

Arrays don't have an `add` method, you need to keep track of the index yourself.

You're currently only splitting on spaces, so `87,000,000` will also match. You could validate the string manually to ensure it consists of only letters.

It's `>=`, not `=>`.

I believe the function needs to return an array:

```
public static String[] getBigWords(String sentence)
```

It actually needs to return something:

```
return result.toArray(new String[0]);
```

rather than

```
return null;
```

The `"You might want to use"` suggestions points to that you might have to process the array character by character.

Comment: I've now got it working, but the assignment software still giving me a compiling error upon turnin. I stated the error in my update, any thoughts?

Comment: @KelvinNguyen Working or compiling? See edit (at the bottom).

Comment: What exactly do you mean character by character? As in have it process each character to verify it is a letter? As opposed to the .matches function?

Comment: @KelvinNguyen I mean instead of the `split` function, have a for-loop go through the string and verify letters and, if you get to a space and all verification succeeded up to now and the length is >= 5, then add it to the output. Obviously more complicated than what you have, but this appears to be what the suggestions point to.

Comment: when I create the method in BlueJ, it works perfectly.  Returns the information I want exactly how it should be, but when I input the method into the assignment turn in site, it gives me that message: "you may need..."

Comment: @KelvinNguyen Is the code exactly as you posted above? Because that's just printing it out in the method, rather than returning it.

Comment: @KelvinNguyen Yeah, so you probably need to do it character by character then.

Answer (score 1):

First, try and print out all the elements in your `split` array. Remember, you do only want you look at words. So, examine if this is the case by printing out each element of the `split` array inside your for loop. (I'm suspecting you will get a false positive at the moment)

Also, you need to revisit your books on arrays in Java. You can not dynamically add elements to an array. So, you will need a different data structure to be able to use an add() method. An ArrayList of Strings would help you here.

Comment: Thank you, I got it to print out the words properly now. Still uncertain as to why the software I use to turn in the assignment says it's work.  I gave the error message, any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

split your string on bases of white space, it will return an array. You can check the length of each word by iterating on that array.
you can split string though this way `myString.split("\\s+");`

Comment: So it has to be "\\s+" instead of the "\\s" that I have?

Comment: Doesn't matter, you can use both "\\s+" or "\\s"

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
public static String[] getBigWords(String sentence)
    {
        java.util.ArrayList<String> result = new java.util.ArrayList<String>();
        String[] split = sentence.split("\\s+");
        for(int i = 0; i < split.length; i++)
        {
            if(split[i].length() > 5)
            {
                if(split[i].matches("[a-zA-Z]+"))
                {
                    result.add(split[i]);
                }
                if (split[i].matches("[a-zA-Z]+,"))
                {
                    String temp = "";
                    for(int j = 0; j < split[i].length(); j++)
                    {
                        if((split[i].charAt(j))!=((char)','))
                        {
                            temp += split[i].charAt(j);
                            //System.out.print(split[i].charAt(j) + "|");
                        }
                    }
                    result.add(temp);
                }
            }
        }
        return result.toArray(new String[0]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is valid, but you have some syntax issues. If you are not using an IDE like Eclipse that shows you syntax errors, try commenting out lines to pinpoint which ones are syntactically incorrect. I want to also tell you that once an array is created its length cannot change. Hopefully that sets you off in the right directions.

Answer (score 0):

Whet you have done is correct but you can't you add method in array. You should set like a[position]= spilt[i]; if you want to ignore number then check by Float.isNumber() method.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from syntax errors at String array declaration should be like new String[n]
and add method will not be there in Array hence you should use like 
a[i] = split[i];

You need to add another condition along with length condition to check that the given word have all letters this can be done in 2 ways

first way is to use Character.isLetter() method and second way is create regular expression 
to check string have only letter. google it for regular expression and use matcher to match like the below
        Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile();
        Matcher matcher=pattern.matcher();

Final point is use another counter (let say j=0) to store output values and increment this counter as and when you store string in the array. 
a[j++] = split[i];

Answer (score 0):

I would use a string tokenizer (string tokenizer class in java)

Iterate through each entry and if the string length is more than 4 (or whatever you need) add to the array you are returning.

You said no code, so...  (This is like 5 lines of code)